# Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 3 for page (1:401831), database ID 8

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm getting the below error while insert record into a SQL 2005 SP3 DB.

Msg 845, Level 17, State 1, Line 1
Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 3 for page (1:401831), database ID 8.

What does "page (1:401831)" refer to is this a memory allocation or a disk allocation?

Reason I'm asking is that the errors always refer to the same page. Removing the record being inserted resolves the issue for a while, but then appears again for a different record.

As such I believe that whatever the page refers to is corrupted and SQL can't read from it.

The record being inserted is pulled from a remote OLTP SQL server to a DataWareHouse server, failing in on the DWH server. Another DWH server copied the same record fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's the identifier for an 8k page in the database. "On disk" or "in memory" is somewhat irrelevant because the answer can be "yes" to both simultaneously. You can look at the contents of the page with `dbcc page(8, 1, 401831)`. dbcc page is undocumented, but you can find plenty of information about it and how to interpret the output out there. NB: by default, the output will go to the errorlog. If you want it to come back to your SSMS (or however you're running the command), issue a `dbcc traceon(3604)` first.